# Printf as argument in for loop in C Programming

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

How this program will be executed? I know basic for loop execution but in this case how the the condition will be checked and how increment will be done?

```
int i = 0;
for(printf("%d",++i);printf("%d",++i);printf("%d",++i)){
  printf("%d",++i);
  if(i>6)
    break;
}
```

Comment: First learn what [`printf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Return_value). Then use a debugger to step through the code while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Replace each `printf()` with different output and try again.  E.g 1st `printf("%d",++i)` --> `printf("A %d\n",++i)`. 2nd `printf("%d",++i);` --> `printf("B %d\n",++i);` ...

Comment: Is this homework or curiosity? Anyway, this piece of code is totally weird.

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop:

```
for (A, B, C) {
    D
}

Order of execution:
A
Loop {
    B
    if result of B is false, break
    D
    C
}
```

In your case, B is never false, so it will do these:

- print 1 (A)
- print 2 (B)
- print 3 (D)
- if statement: 3>6 is false (D)
- print 4 (C)
- print 5 (B)
- print 6 (D)
- if statement: 6>6 is false (D)
- print 7 (C)
- print 8 (B)
- print 9 (D)
- if statement: 9>6 is true, break (D)

Comment: Wrong answer. Check what printf returns. man 3 printf

Comment: @rurban Define [wrong](https://godbolt.org/z/W9MzMz), please ;)

Comment: @rurban - the return value of `printf` only matters in one place, and as this code is written will return a non-zero value for the duration of this loop.  Why is this answer wrong?

Answer (score -2):

In your code add \n in printed function.

It is simple.
plz try my pgm.

Try to count execution of for loop.